# Syncrepl support in Mac OSx 10.8 OpenDirectory

Tags: mac-osx, replication, mac-osx-server, opendirectory

From Ryan Faas's [article](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1153427) Apple's OpenDirectory does support overlays but I can't seem to enable the syncprov or accesslog overlays. Adding following block to slapd_macosxserver.conf turns the server in to vegetable.

```
# defines replica provider for this database
overlay syncprov

# contextCSN saved to database every 1000 updates or 60 minutes
syncprov-checkpoint 1000 60
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The OpenDirectory implementation in 10.8 has changed considerably since Leopard. This may no longer be supported. What is the end goal of enabling the syncprov overlay?

Comment: Hi Phillip, thanks for replying. I am trying to setup access log delta-sync for my software.